# How to implement Knn in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, nearest-neighbor, knn

I've to implement k-nearest neighbor algorithm in Matlab by using [the iris data](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data).
There are 3 types of flowers and each contains 50 samples. I need to take 1st 25 samples of each class as training data and last 25 as training data.
I've tried some sites and methods but nothing has worked not even `fitcknn` - Matlab built-in function always give this error:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'fitcknn' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Comment: `fitcknn` is part of the statistics toolbox, is this toolbox licensed and installed?

Comment: @Daniel just installed Matlab don't know whether its installed or not :/

Comment: Log in with your mathworks account, click on "manage license", there you can see a list of all licensed toolbox. If it is listed there, download the installer and the toolbox and install it.

Comment: Alternatively, use the [`ver`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ver.html) command in the command window.

Comment: Does ver list toolboxes which are licensed but not installiert?

Comment: @Daniel don't have an account

Comment: Then ask the person who manages the license.

Comment: @Daniel can you help on building algorithm?

Comment: @Schorsch ver gave Statistics toolbox 7.5 and etc etc

Comment: @HelpingDesk: Instead of reimplementing, I would use one of the many available java implementations. I don't know why `fitcknn` isn't available in your case, maybe a newer matlab version is required.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are referring to the online documentation, which is for R2014a Release.

For earlier versions, KNN is `ClassificationKNN`.

So you should use `ClassificationKNN.fit(X, Y)` instead.